# Java - Open a URL from a string

Tags: java, android

I plan on having a bunch of URLs specified in `strings.xml`, eg:

```
<string name="a1_url">https://en.wikipedia.org</string>
```

I would like to be able to open a URL (eg string name "a1_url") from an activity, but can't figure out how to reference the string name in Uri.parse. This current code works fine when you hardcode the URL:

```
Intent i2=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://en.wikipedia.org"));
                startActivity(i2);
```

My overall goal is to have many URLs as strings and the app will choose one for you at random, eg `a1_url` or `a233_url`.

Comment: You can get the value from `string.xml` with `getString()` method of `Context`. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getString(int,%20java.lang.Object...)

Comment: please don't include the android studio tag just because you're using it to develop your app, only use it if you're asking about a feature of the ide specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to load the string value from resources XML

```java
String url = getString(R.string.a1_url);
```

Then use it in your intent

Comment: Perfect, here's the end result:
String url = getString(R.string.a1_url);
                Intent i2=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i2=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(R.string.a1_url));
            startActivity(i2);
```